# puppet - missing openjdk-6-jdk

Tags: puppet, java

I am trying to run a script with puppet. I have absolutely no idea about how puppet works

When I run the following command:

> facter_user=nbui facter_group=staff puppet apply
>   --node_name_value=mac_local --modulepath=/foobar/sysops/aws/puppet/modules /foobar/sysops/aws/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp

I get the following error:

> Could not find dependency Package[openjdk-6-jdk] for
>   Exec[elasticsearch-package] at
>   /foobar/sysops/aws/puppet/modules/elasticsearch/manifests/init.pp:76

I looked for error but could not find anything good.

According to the error I feel java is missing, but Mac - OSX already ships with open-jdk right?

Also I am able to run "`javac`"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Puppet.

So, the error is that the specific package named "openjdk-6-jdk" can't be installed on your machine, and isn't already there.

Given that you are on a Mac, as indicated, that isn't a great surprise - you wouldn't use that package anyhow.

So, the manifest - the Puppet code that contains the instruction to install that package - isn't built to work on MacOS.  (...and we can only be as good as the instructions we get.)

You need to get in touch with the folks who wrote the manifest and get them to add OS-X support, or to run that on a platform that those folks supported in their manifest.

(...or learn enough Puppet to fix their bug, of course. :)

Comment: My colleagues are running mac & for them the script runs perfectly well

Comment: Uhm, no, that error means that there's no package resource defined -- he's missing some manifest file or fragment that defines that resource.  The package itself may well be available, or even installed.

Comment: Could you please help me figure that out ?